# Strange logic behaviour in PHP - is this normal?

Tags: php, logic

Can anyone figure out why this might happen in PHP (am using v5.4):

```php
$value = 0;
$existing_value = "Unknown";

if ($value == $existing_value) {
    echo "$value == $existing_value";
} else {
    echo "$value != $existing_value";
}
```

This outputs as `0 == Unknown`

Interestingly, `$value = "0"` (i.e. set as a string), evaluates to be false

Is this a known behaviour?  Have I missed something in the documentation on this?  Debugging this was driving me crazy earlier today!

Thanks for your help in advance...

Comment: I think it is because you echo it as a string. It is not `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the automatic type casting, PHP uses.

When comparing an int value with a string using just `==`, the string will be casted to an int, which in your case results in a `0` and hence a `true` evaluation.

See the respective [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) for more information.

To circumvent this, you could use `===` instead of `==`. The former includes a type check, which will make your condition evaluate to false:

```
$value = 0;
$existing_value = "Unknown";

if ($value === $existing_value) {
    echo "$value === $existing_value";
} else {
    echo "$value !== $existing_value";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  As I am using this code in a function to determine whcih existing value should be pre-selected in a drop-down list, I think my preferred option is to convert both parts to strings and do the test `if (strval($value) == strval($existing_value))`  Am I correct that this will have a consistent result whereever it is used?

Comment: @user2761030 I think a consistent coding and using `===` would be the better choice, but string conversion should work as well, I think.

Comment: The thing is, it's a live site and I'm not certain that all values across the site will come through (from a DB/user input etc) as their correct variable types (stings, boolean etc) so `===` might cause different unexpected behaviours elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

When you compare a number with a string in PHP, as you do here, the string is converted to a number. Since the string "Unknown" is not numeric, it's converted to the number `0`.

If you check for equality with the `===` operator, it won't perform type conversion and it'll evaluate as false.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [comparison tables in PHP](https://www.php.net/types.comparisons) Especially the loose comparison (using ==) section as compared to the strict comparison (using ===) section.

[image]

Comment: a screenshot might be a good idea. right now the table you posted is just confusing

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thanks, always assumed the site would need me to host my own images on a server somewhere and that was always going to be too much work. I learned something new today :)